# Asp.Net MVC Route does not Display "Index" value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

When i redirect from a Controller using

```
RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller");
```

Or Generate a link with UrlHelper

```
@Url.Action("Index","Controller");
```

In both ways the "/Index" Part is striped down from my URL.
Although for SEO Purposes i want my url to be displayed always at the same manner.

***www.domain.com/en/Controller/Index***

but now i get

***www.domain.com/en/Controller***

How can i force these two methods above always display the "/Index" Part.

P.S I know this happens because "Index" is indicated as a Default action on my route, but either way i want it to be displayed.

Comment: Why do you want to include that for SEO purposes? A simpler URL will be **far** more important for SEO.

Comment: mostly because i have manually generated rel="canonical" tags that i want to be matched.

Comment: yes you are right. I could not find your linked answer before.

Comment: @Anestis Kivranoglou Is your problem solved with new route role ?

Comment: Although it is a solution it adds 1 extra route as burden , i am still looking for alternatives.

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou Did you found alternative or my answer is the only solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Add new role in RouteConfig with before default route with Index action

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultIndex",
            url: "{controller}/Index/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration inside `global.asax` file. It can be like this.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Controller", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
  }
```

Maybe based on your mask you always going to default route. So just remove default mapping.

Comment: You need to have **some** default route. If you removed all of them, nothing would work.

Comment: You can map to your strict url if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return RedirectToAction("About","Home");
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```